# Unbound variable error with if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fileName' referenced before assignment' when using variables underneath if/elif statements.

The code takes a file name and uses a regex to split the junk off the start and end. It then returns the new filename and foldername.:

```
input:
'[subcompany] series title - 01 [more junk].mkv'

desired output:
('series title - 01.mkv', 'series title')
```

troublesome code:

```
def nameFix(f):
    start, end = os.path.splitext(f)

    if f.endswith('mkv') and f.startswith('[H'):
        fileName = fileReg.findall(f)
    elif f.endswith('mkv') and f.startswith('['):
        fileName=altReg.findall(f)


    folder = folderReg.findall(fileName[0][1])
    fileFix = fileName[0][1] + end
    fixFolderName = folder[0]
    return (fileFix, fixFolderName)
```

Comment: Try to add comments to your code with input and expected output. It is a good practice. You got multiple variables without explanation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, because you have no `else` clause, if neither the `if` or the `elif` conditions evaluate to `True`, `fileName` is not defined. Perhaps try returning `f` in an `else` clause so that the function exits:

```
if f.endswith('mkv') and f.startswith('[H'):
    fileName = fileReg.findall(f)
elif f.endswith('mkv') and f.startswith('['):
    fileName=altReg.findall(f)
else:
    return f
```

Answer (score 0):

clearly the if and elif statements have not run and so fileName is not assigned yet so the error is simply saying-"this is not a variable"

Comment: as the other answer says the solution would be to have a else statement assigning fileName seperately as a default name

Comment: btw if you return None there will be no result and the extra code will not run so the problem is not solved