# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'di' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, global

I know there's many questions about this problem, but after having been looking for a solution on the internet for a while nothing have work. 
Here's my code:

```
def posicio_relativ(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):
    if x1<x2:
        di='dreta'
    if x1>x2:
        di='esquerra'
    if y1<y2:
        ss='sobre'
    if y1>y2:
        ss='sota'
    if z1<z2:
        dd='davant'
    if z1>z2:
        dd='darrera'
    return di, ss, dd
```

I'm a begginer in using python, so I would aprecciate any help or explaination.

Thank you in advanced!

P.D: sorry for my English, I'm from Spain!

Comment: If `x1<x2` is not true, then `di` never gets assigned, and can't be returned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unbound variable error with if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629555/unbound-variable-error-with-if-statements)

Comment: For all of ``x``, ``y`` and ``z`` you are missing the case of equality. For example, you have ``x1 < x2`` and ``x1 > x2`` but not ``x1 == x2``.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to declare the values `di`, `ss`, and `dd` and initialise them as blank strings before your `if` statements. For example, if `x1 == x2` then `di` will never get initialised.

```
def posicio_relativ(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):

    di = ''
    ss = ''
    dd = ''

    if x1<x2:
        di='dreta'
    if x1>x2:
        di='esquerra'
    if y1<y2:
        ss='sobre'
    if y1>y2:
        ss='sota'
    if z1<z2:
        dd='davant'
    if z1>z2:
        dd='darrera'
    return di, ss, dd
```

Comment: Just to add on @Cam's reply, please have a look into official doc https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Answer (score 1):

The variable `di` is created within one of these if statements:

```
   if x1<x2:
        di='dreta'
    if x1>x2:
        di='esquerra'
```

The problem is that if x1 == x2 then you code doesn't go to any of this if statements.

So when you call `return di, ss, dd` the variable `di` doesn't exist.

One quick fix for that is just to set one of your if statement to be `x1 >= x2` or `x1 <= x2`

Answer (score 1):

you have to make sure your variables get assigned in all casses which isnt the case
x1==x2 y1==y2 z1==z2 arent covered.
so you could do:

```
def posicio_relativ(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):

    di='dreta'
    if x1>x2:
        di='esquerra'

    ss='sobre'
    if y1>y2:
        ss='sota'

    dd='davant'
    if z1>z2:
        dd='darrera'

    return di, ss, dd
```

depending on what your disired behavior is for those cases you would need to do something different maybe

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!